# How to iterate two different object list and modify object property of one list based on element present in the other list

Tags: java

I am trying to filter an existing object list based on the element present in another list. Now if the both the element matches, I need to modify an object property in one of the list. How this can be achieved in java 8?

```
public class Slot {
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Date startDate;
    private Status status;
}

List<java.util.Date> dateList;
List<Slot> slotList;
```

So basically if elements of `dateList` are present in `slotList`, I want to modify the status attribute. This can be done using traditional looping but I am looking for an efficient java 8 way.

Comment: I'd doubt using streams etc. would make it more efficient that a traditional loop, except if you plan on running parallel streams. What might help more, depending on the size of the lists, might be to convert `dateList` to a set and then iterate over the slots and checking whether a slot's date is contained in that date set. If you have many slots and few matches there might be other approaches/algorithms to make it more efficient but using Java 8's streams would not be one of them.

Answer (score 2):

```
slotList
  // find slots with dates that are in the datelist 
  .filter(slot -> dateList.contains(slot.getDate()))
  //  update each slot that was found via the above predicate
  .forEach(slot -> slot.setStatus("new status"));
```

Comment: some explanation would be helpful, not just code drop

Comment: Java list does not have `exists()` perhaps you meant `contains()`?

Comment: Another way is to use dateList.stream().allMatch(d.equals(slot.getDate()))

Comment: you meant anyMatch()